# Store iteritems-Result in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteritems

**Goal:**
Add a column ('Team_url') to my nfl teams dataframe (df_teams) with each teams website-url.

**Problem:**
If I print the url, it works just fine. If I try to store it to df_teams['Team_url'], it only stores the last result of the iteritems.

**Data:**

```
df_teams['Team_web']

0            Arizona-Cardinals
1                Chicago-Bears
2            Green-Bay-Packers
3              New-York-Giants
4                Detroit-Lions
.
.
.
31              Houston-Texans
```

**Code:**

```
for i, j in df_teams['Team_web'].iteritems():
    url_1 = "https://www.nfl.com/teams/{0}/roster".format(j)
    df_teams['Team_url'] = url_1
```

**Print:**

```
print(url_1):

https://www.nfl. com/teams/Arizona-Cardinals/roster
https://www.nfl. com/teams/Chicago-Bears/roster
.
.
.
https://www.nfl.com/teams/Houston-Texans/roster

print(df_teams['Team_url'])

0     https://www.nfl.com/teams/Houston-Texans/roster
1     https://www.nfl.com/teams/Houston-Texans/roster
2     https://www.nfl.com/teams/Houston-Texans/roster
```

**Questions:**
How can I store what is printed for the url_1 in the dataframe column?

Comment: Your code `df_teams['Team_url'] = url_1` is assigning to the whole column, instead of just one row of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Team_url'] = 'https://www.nfl.com/teams/' + df['Team_web'] + '/roster'
```

[image]